# Jquery to add class in H1 tag in div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to add class H1 tag inside div tag

```
function MatchReplace(content)
              {  
                  var input = content;
                  **$j('.wmd-preview').children().addClass('overridedefault');

 input = content.replace(/\<h1>/gi, "<h1 class='overridedefault'>");**
}
```

Tried both children() and add class but it's not added.
please let me know if am missing something here

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#add").click(function(){
  $('#adhere>h1').addClass("green")

})

$( "#target" ).keyup(function() {
  $('#adhere>h1').addClass("green")
});
```

```css
#adhere{
border: red 1px solid;

}

.green{
color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="adhere"><h1>This is H1</h1></div>
<button id='add'>add class</button>
<input type="text" id="target" />
```

Comment: Thanks ! i dont want to add h1 tag just wanna add class to the h1 element inside div

Comment: @SSAT where you want to have that key up event??

Answer (score 0):

try this to add the class to the first H1 tag into div 
http://jsfiddle.net/mig1098/xd9ahwbw/

```
addingclass = function(_class){  
    $('.wmd-preview').find('h1').first().addClass(_class);
}
```